# What are the differences between using an iframe and ajax to include the contents of an external page?

Tags: ajax, iframe, external

I have been reading up on this, and it seems that if you use ajax you can only bring in content that resides on the same domain whereas with an iframe you can bring in content from any domain.  Is that the case?  What other differences are there?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bear in mind they're two completely separate technologies.

A (i)frame really loads a complete HTML page in area into the browser. Whether the page is on the same or another domain, for pure viewing, doesn't matter.

Ajax only describes a system to facilitate JavaScript to talk with (and with current security restriction across browser, only with) the server from which you document within which you generated the JavaScript call from.

The (i)frame technology loads and renders a complete HTML page from any URL given. Certain security restrictions accessing other documents from other domains with JavaScript still apply.

With Ajax, it's only meant to use purely JavaScript to talk to the originating server (send some data) and usually get some data back. In JavaScript. What this data is and what you do with it, is up to you. Whether you insert it into the DOM (Document Object Model), exchange parts or load a new page is up to you.

To a certain degree you have all freedom you want. You can have an (i)frame on a page, still make a Ajax call and decide to load another URL into the (i)frame. Or use the Ajax return value to generate new HTML dynamically inside the (i)frame. Or outside, in another document.

The security restrictions applying in this case is called "same origin policy".

Comment: So if you were deciding on what technology to use to show external pages would you use iframe then?  As you can tell, I am not a developer, but I like to understand best practices so when I talk to my developers I have a bit of understanding.

Comment: I cannot foresee your complete use of what you really need, *but* given your information it *may* be appropriate.

Generally, using (i)frames is not recommended for they create usability problems of all sorts; Keyboard navigation, bookmarking

However circumstances may leave this as the only option.

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, an iframe is like a regular frame, but it doesn't split the browser window up into sections, it sits right inside a page and is affected by the scrollbar.

Ajax, on the other hand, uses javascript to do partial loads of a page, allowing small amounts of data to be loaded from the server without needing to do a complete postback.  For example, Youtube uses Ajax when you post comments, vote, queue videos to play, etc.  They do this so that your video isn't interrupted and restarted by a complete page postback.

Answer (score 0):

Besides these differences mentioned by others, there are others as well.
iframe loads an entire html/php page, whether it is from the own server or other external server. Usually, it has a fresh `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tag as well. Ajax only loads part of the html/php page.

Besides, Ajax pulls the CSS (and maybe, even javascript codes) from the parent file, but in case of Iframe, it cannot pull the same.

E.g this is the master file coding.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .gappu {background-color:black;color:red;}
</style>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="../AllJqueries/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> <!-- Use your own jQuery file -->
    <script>
        <!--
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({url:"slave1.php?bare=true", success:function(data){
                $(".myDomain").html(data);
            }});
        }); /* End of Main Jquery */
        //-->
    </script>
<title>Ajax vs Iframe</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="myDomain"></div>
    <div>Iframe below</div>
    <iframe width="100%" height="500px" src="slave1.php"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, we also have another file, named as slave1.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['bare'])) $bare = $_GET['bare'];
else $bare = false;
if(!$bare):
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    .gappu {background-color:blue;color:yellow;}
</style>
<!-- You can remove the above style later, and see the difference. The parent style will not apply for iframe -->
<title>Inside the Iframe</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php endif; ?>
    <div class="gappu">Hi, welcome to this demo</div>
<?php if(!$bare): ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php endif;
```

In case of Ajax call, the line **Hi, welcome to this demo** will be in black background and red color, since it is borrowing the css from the parent. But in iframe, it will be in blue background and white color, which is defined in slave1.php. You can remove the style from slave1.php, and you will find plain text printed in iframe format.

Hope this helps. Cheers.
Vijay Srinivas